# Firebase Deployment error, it seems facing problem when it run creating Node.js 16 function app (us-central1)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am deploying express application to firebase Functions. But receiving error when it's doing functions: creating Node.js 16 function app (us-central1)...

Here are my ExpressJS sample under "Functions" folder. I not quite sure what is happening

```
const express = require('express')
const firebasefunctions = require('firebase-functions')
const cors = require('cors')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');
dotenv.config();


const app = express()
const port = process.env.DB_PORT

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())

const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host : process.env.DB_HOST,
      port : process.env.DB_DO_PORT,
      user : process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password : process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database : process.env.DB_DO,
      ssl: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync('./ca-certificate.crt').toString()
      }
    }
});

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    knex.select().table('tablename')
    .then(response => res.json(response))
    .catch(console.log)
    
})

app.post('/update', (req, res) => {
    
    console.log(req.body)
    req.body.forEach(item => {
        knex('tablename')
        .where('number', '=', item)
        .increment({
            occurence: 1
        })
        .catch(console.log)
    })
    res.json("Success")
})

exports.app = firebasefunctions.https.onRequest(app)
```

And also the package.json under "Functions"

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The error debug looks like this
[image: Firebase-debug-log]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: It seems that you think this knex module is going to work in Cloud Functions with environment variables that you can't set.  I highly suspect it will not work at all.

Comment: Ya I try to remove the knex module then it works. But I got a database somewhere on digital ocean, is there any way for me to do the query?

Comment: Questions like "is there any way to..." are off topic for Stack Overflow.  Do web searches to research the problem, make an attempt, and debug it on your own.  If you have a problem, post your problem statement here with your debugging details.

Comment: Thanks. I will try from my site. Perhaps will try move both to firebase real time database with hosting